# How to import C++ header file, from static library, into Obj-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I am have a third-party static library, which includes a header file written in C++. I have linked the library, but get compile errors, because the header file uses #include  gives a file not found error. It is a library, so I don't think I should be editing that file at all, so is there so flag or property to change in the project settings to compile that header file?

The error is happening in: ViewRightWebiOS.h

The specific line the error is on the third line:

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: How does the header file use #import? - Do you mean you #import the C++ header file - your wording implies the C++ header file uses #import

Comment: Objective-C has no knowledge of C++ constructs.. ie: destructors. Your header file must be plain C or plain Objective-C. You cannot expect to use `<string>` with `std::string` in Objective-C. Instead, export your data to use `const char*` or `char*` respectively.

Comment: @Mark - sorry typo I meant include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ headers can only be imported not a file compiled with C++.

The easy way to do this is to rename the file containing the #include to have an extension of .mm rather than the Objective C normal extension of .m  Xcode will compile this file using the Objective-C++ dialect. In this mode C++ and Objective C constructs are understood in the same file. However you can use Objective C features on a C++ object and vice versa, interoperation is still using commonly understood C constructs

Comment: This solved the first error, but it turns out there is something very wrong in the actual proprietary library used, I will submit a support ticket to them. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you should include the file in your implementation file (.m) file, but rename it to .mm. This way you'll actually be using objective-c++, but it should be ok.